# Binning 2D data into overlapping circles in x,y

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, histogram, binning

I'm currently working with a fairly large dataset of 3D points (x,y,z) and would like an efficient means to identify which points are inside a set of circles in the xy plane, with radius r and centre (x1,y1), where x1 and y1 are grid coordinates (of length 120 each). The circles will overlap, and some points will belong to multiple circles.

So the output would be the identities of 14400 circles (120*120), and which points in the (x,y,z) list are in each one.

```
import numpy as np

def inside_circle(x, y, x0, y0, r):
    return (x - x0)*(x - x0) + (y - y0)*(y - y0) < r*r

x = np.random.random_sample((10000,))
y = np.random.random_sample((10000,))

x0 = np.linspace(min(x),max(x),120)
y0 = np.linspace(min(y),max(y),120)

idx = np.zeros((14400,10000))
r = 2
count = 0

for i in range(0,120):
    for j in range(0,120):
        idx[count,:] = inside_circle(x,y,x0[i],y0[j],r)
        count = count + 1
```

where inside_circle is a function that gives an array of boolean True or False for each tested point x,y,z in circle of radius r, with centre x0[i] and x0[j]

My main question is whether there is a more efficient way to do this than a nested for loop? Or even more efficient means to do anything here in general - as i'm quite new to python.

Thanks for any responses!

Alec.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People can't run your current code

Comment: How can a point in 3d be inside a circle? Do you mean inside the cylinder given by projecting the circle in the direction of the z axis?

Comment: Yes, I do mean inside a cylinder (so just circles on the x,y plane)

Answer (score 0):

This one uses array broadcasting and is slightly faster than the nested for loops (0.5s vs 0.8s on my machine). The readability has decreased though in my view.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.random_sample((1, 10000))
y = np.random.random_sample((1, 10000))

x0 = np.reshape(np.linspace(np.min(x),np.max(x),120), (120, 1))
y0 = np.reshape(np.linspace(np.min(y),np.max(y),120), (120, 1))

r = 2

all_xdiffssquared = np.subtract(x, x0)**2
all_ydiffssquared = np.subtract(y, y0)**2
# 3d here means that the array has 3 dimensions. Not the geometry described
all_xdiffssquared_3d = np.reshape(all_xdiffssquared, (120, 10000, 1))
all_ydiffssquared_3d = np.reshape(np.transpose(all_ydiffssquared), (1, 10000, 120))
all_distances_3d = all_xdiffssquared_3d + all_ydiffssquared_3d - r**2
idx = np.signbit(np.reshape(np.moveaxis(all_distances_3d, 1, -1), (14400, 10000)))
```